# Akka-Http File Upload sending response before request is completely read

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have the following route in my akka-http server:

```
def tempDestination(fileInfo: FileInfo): File = {
    log.info(s"File info for upload: [$fileInfo]")
    File.createTempFile(fileInfo.fileName, ".tmp")
}
...
post {
    log.info("Inside the file upload path")
    fileUpload("zip") {
      case (fileInfo, bytes) =>
        val dest = tempDestination(fileInfo)
        val uploadedF: Future[(FileInfo, File)] =
          bytes
            .runWith(FileIO.toPath(dest.toPath))
            .map(_ => (fileInfo, dest))

        onSuccess(uploadedF) { (info, file) =>
            val fileCreated: Future[MyFile] = (fileRegistryActor ? NewFile(file)).mapTo[MyFile]
            complete((StatusCodes.Created, fileCreated))
        }
    }
}
```

After uploading a file to this via a form, I see this in the logs:

```
Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received... Note that the connection will be closed after this response. Also, many clients will not read early responses! Consider only issuing this response after the request data has been completely read!
```

I thought that the `uploadedF` Future would not be completed until the Sink's IOResult was created and completed. What am I missing? And what's the proper mechanism to determine whether my whole request has been read AND my file has been completely written to disk?

Comment: Hmm you might have too many futures going on,  try runWith().flatmap()

Comment: also at the bottom fileCreated is a future, so you'll presumably want to map over that (like you do withuploadedF) in order call complete

Comment: If I `runWith().flatMap()` then my body needs to return a `Future[(FileInfo, File)]` instead of just the `(FileInfo, File)` that I have. I can try mapping over the `fileCreated` future, but from looking at the pre-made templates, calling `complete()` with a Future is doable and the complete will just be finished after the Future is resolved.

Comment: Also if I map over `fileCreated` then I need to specifically Await on the Future, since the return of onSuccess needs to be a `Route` not a `Future[Route]`

Comment: The body of `onSuccess` there is only being called with a successful `IOResult` so far. I think the problem is that the File is being written to disk before the request is complete, and I'm just waiting on the file, not the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what appeared to solve this for me was changing the route from just `post` to `post & extractRequest`.

```
def tempDestination(fileInfo: FileInfo): File = {
    log.info(s"File info for upload: [$fileInfo]")
    File.createTempFile(fileInfo.fileName, ".tmp")
}
...
(post & extractRequest) { _ =>
    log.info("Inside the file upload path")
    fileUpload("zip") {
      case (fileInfo, bytes) =>
        val dest = tempDestination(fileInfo)
        val uploadedF: Future[(FileInfo, File)] =
          bytes
            .runWith(FileIO.toPath(dest.toPath))
            .map(_ => (fileInfo, dest))

        onSuccess(uploadedF) { (info, file) =>
            val fileCreated: Future[MyFile] = (fileRegistryActor ? NewFile(file)).mapTo[MyFile]
            complete((StatusCodes.Created, fileCreated))
        }
    }
}
```